# Introduction to Thermodynamic Formalism?

Tags: reference-request

I am searching for an introduction into thermodynamic formalism. I am studying mathematics and would like to get to know this. Maybe you can recommend some books or articles that are good for an introduction?

Some notions are Gibbs-measures, pressure, entropy.

Comment: May I suggest you move this to physics.stackexchange?

Comment: @SeanLake I would prefer not since I am no physicist and am mainly interested in the mathematical formulation.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can have a look at the following notes by Charles Walkden https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/charles.walkden/magic/ .

2) Some more notes by Henk Bruin https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~bruin/TF.pdf .

3)For more depth you can check "Thermodynamic formalism for countable Markov shifts" by Omri M. Sarig.

The transfer operator method in the following book is also relevant "Ergodic Theory, Symbolic Dynamics, and Hyperbolic Spaces (Oxford Science Publications)".

Just to say